# Mysql - Multiple OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if it is possible to transform this code

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz=3
OR baz=4
OR baz=5
```

into something like this

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz=3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` operator.

`IN` operator allows you to specify multiple values in a `WHERE` clause.

### Query

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz IN (3,4,5);
```